# Стат сумма, хеширование, контрольная сумма для сравнения двух текстовых строк.

Tags: алгоритм, хеширование

Есть следующая задача, допустим, есть текстовые строки одинаковой длины. 
Допустим, используются только буквы ABCD. Нужно ввести метрику, способ подсчёта контрольной суммы и тп. (не знаю как более точно обозвать), чтобы можно было сравнивать строки между собой по их контрольным суммам.

То есть:

ABCDABCD и ABCDABCC - очень близкие строки с одной заменой. (1)

ABCDABCD и ABCDDABC - тоже очень близкие строки с одной вставкой "D".

Насколько я представляю, нужно иметь на выходе некоторую постоянную и вариабельную часть.

Чтобы в первом примере (1) SUM(ABCDABCD)='wtyy45t'.004 а SUM(ABCDABCC)='wtyy45t'.007 (цифры и буквы условны).

И в тоже время:  SUM(ABCDABCD)='wtyy45t'.004 а SUM(DDACBADB)='yiejq07'.163

Чтобы можно было потом легко сравнивать похожие строки и откидывать совсем разные.

Буду благодарен за любые ссылки на алгоритмы, предложения, советы. Спасибо.

**UPD**
Основной момент - различных строк будет несколько сотен тысяч. Нет возможности их сравнивать между собой по сложным критериям. Хочется группировать их в кластеры по общей постоянной части контрольной суммы.

Comment: @slipshod, это анализ генома, что ли?

Уточните, (отбросив суммы, хэши т.п. низкоуровневые части алгоритма) что надо делать с этими сотнями тысяч? Как часто этот набор (группируемый в кластеры) меняется ?

Comment: @avp ООочень примерный анализ генома - это с точностью 70% человек похож на утконоса с вероятностью 1. Какая-то приблизительная задача. Сравнивать строки нельзя, метрика нелинейная.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, геном не геном - не важно. Хочется уточнения. 

--

Цель - это разбиение множества строк на кластеры без анализа каждый-с-каждым ? Т.е. автор хочет алгоритм, который для строки вырабатывает число (номер кластера) и *похожие* строки будут иметь один и тот же номер ?

Comment: Ключевое слово _похожие_. Функция похожести определена только для каждых двух строк. Учитывая вставку, удаление, замену, еще есть и транспозиция, функция транзитивной не является.  
В качестве доказательства утверждения можно использовать игру "как из мухи сделать слона", получив кластер из непохожих слов тупо заменой, без удалений и вставок.

Comment: Уточните задачу. Зачем все это нужно. Одно дело если нужно БЫСТРО находить какую-то конкретную строку. Другое дело - если требуется сжать весь этот "словарь" (для архивации тоже зачастую используются словарные методики)

Answer (score 2):

Как уже отметил margosh, вам следует уточнить требуемое понятие похожести, алгоритма `is_strings_similar_like_i_want` нет, и подобной функции не найдете даже в пхп. Пока можно рекомендовать полистать [Энциклопедический словарь расстояний](http://lib.mexmat.ru/books/87507), в главе 11 приведены все известные метрики на множествах строк.

Comment: благодарю, уточнения дал.

Answer (score 2):

Есть некие мысли по поводу алгоритма, не уверена что подобное Вам подойдет, но учитывая все вышесказанное, предложения следующие :

1. Выяснить длину строки и предел количества символов, которые могут быть отличны (судя по Вашим пояснениям - 30%)
2. Поисмвольно вычесть одну строку из другой, если количество "ненулевых" символов в результате превышает предел и данные символы располагаются вразброс - в строке были замены, стока по количеству замен отбрасывается, если же ненулевые символы идут строем - на лицо сдвиг или делеция, и необходимо сохранить позицию первого отличного символа и продолжить анализ. Соответственно при количестве "ненулевых" символов в результате меньше предела - строки похожи.
3. Далее, в случае **сдвигов и делеций** должен быть цикл, ограниченный пределом количества отличных символов (Nlim), в котором проверяются : сопадение первого несовпавшего символа (позиция m) с одним из символов последующих позиций базовой строки (но не более m + Nlim). В случае совпадения на некоторой позиции r, проверяется совпадение последующих символов строки m+i с символами базовой строки m+r+i,теоретически, можно вынести эти куски в отдельные строки и воспользоваться пунктом 2.
   Для **вставки** сверяем символы строки в позиции от m до m+Nlim с символом базовой строки в позиции m.

Пример : 
вставка : ABCDABCD и ABCDCDABСD, рез. - 00001111, m=4,r=6, позиции 4-7 базовой и 6-9 совпадают
Как быть со строками разной длины - Вам, как автору темы, виднее.

PS: Эти наброски, безусловно, не претендуют на полноту, простоту и быстроту реализации.

Comment: осталось доказать, что близкие метрики для двух строк, полученные от сравнения с одним шаблоном, скажут что строки близки.  
например.
для шаблона AAA, сравнив с BBB, получим максимальное несоответствие.
значит ли это что при сравнении AAA и CCC получим туже самую метрику максимального несоответствия, и при этом BBB будет близко к CCC?

Comment: здесь ищутся строки, похожие на шаблон, однако да, это не значит, что между собой они будут иметь столько же, или меньше отличий, это просто вариант со своими ограничениями в применении.

Comment: Даже две строки похожие на шаблон на 70% в худшем случае будут похожи друг на друга на 40%. В общем изначальная идея плохая...

Comment: Вопрос в том, надо ли автору, чтобы эти 2 строки были похожи между собой на 70%, а не на шаблон? Я вот, не в курсе, какая конкретно задача преследуется, может необходимо найти и сложить в кучу все строки, в которых определенная вариативная фраза встречается, в этом случае идея подойдет. Если же необходимо, чтобы строки в кластерах не разбегались совсем, всегда можно дополнительно их сравнить.

Comment: @margosh, IMHO автор про шаблон не писал.

Comment: пусть тогда автор уточняет

Comment: не. шаблон (притом любой) должен дать некую информацию о похожести строк между собой, иначе по одному шаблону мы можем получить только один кластер - похожих на него, а остальные строки будут непонятной кучей. в итоге задача сведется к выбору шаблонов равноудаленных по непохожести. и даже в этом случае нет гарантии что мы про все пары строк сможем сказать, что они похожи или нет.
закончится все полным перебором, т.е. тем что предложил @ЫЫЫ, и скорее всего это будет правильно.

Comment: Да, без уточнения конечной цели (а не обсуждения "фиксированной" и "вариабельной" частей суммы) тут ничего не придумать.

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая то что ваши строки имеют одинаковую длину, то я бы ввел метрику редактирования, то есть сколько замен букв требуется, для получения одного слова из другого.
ABCDABCD и ABCDABCC - очень близкие строки с одной заменой. (1)
Алгоритм вычисления данной метрики O(LENGTH(str)).

Comment: Основной момент - различных строк будет несколько сотен тысяч. Нет возможности их сравнивать между собой по сложным критериям.

Comment: а почему вы решили что есть какой-то супер пупер способ который способен сделать все хорошо и быстро? если у вас есть необходимость проанализовать данные то всегда есть 2 варианта: но оба они очень похожи:
1) выбираем самый простой алгоритм, усложняем до тех пор пока данные неприемлимо групируются.
2) выбираем самый сложный алгоритм. оптимизируем. покупаем получше железо. до тех пор пока время неприемлимо упрощаем алгоритм.

в любом случае у вас получится компромис между 2мя вариантами.

Answer (score 1):

Если число используемых символов ограничено какой-то разумной величиной `N` (ну скажем меньше 16), то лучший способ это трансляция строк в некое длинное целое используя в качестве метрики позиционный способ записи N-тиричной системе счисления. Скажем ваш пример с четырьмя символами ABCD - легко ложится под 4-х тиричную систему счисления. Строка:

```
ABCDABCD -> 01230123
ABCDABCC -> 01230122
```

Ну а дальше сравнение целых это уже просто.

Comment: Основной момент - различных строк будет несколько сотен тысяч. Нет возможности их сравнивать между собой по сложным критериям.

Comment: Вычисление любого нормального хэш алгоритма будет довольно ресурсоемким, имхо данный способ довольно дешевый по сравнению с классическим SHA или MD5

Comment: криптографические хэши не удовлетворяют условию задачи - из-за эффекта лавины близкие строки будут иметь существенно разные хэши

Comment: ну хорошо, я с Вами согласен. У меня длина строки 2000 символов.
Преобразую их в 01230123... и 01140122... Как мне сравнить их на похожесть? Задача попарного сравнения мне не нужна, так как мне не нужна процентная оценка их совпадения.  

Я хотел бы придумать алгоритм, который бы оценивал одну строку как есть и ставил ей в соответствие базовую и вариабельную часть стат суммы. То есть оценка некоторого глобального паттерна строки и отклонений от него.

Comment: Преобразуйте в BigInteger и возьмите разницу между ними или поделите друг на друга. Или я чего-то упускаю?

Comment: для самого простого случая может подойти деление по разрядам, обычное деление смысла не имеет. 
однако, даже разрядное деление может дать ложный результат из-за буквенного сдвига (как в примере с дополнительной буквой D: ABCDABCD и ABCDDABC очень похожи, особенно на масштабе тысяч, а любое деление 01230123 на 01233012 ничего не дает).

Comment: @slipshod, а Вы не могли бы уточнить критерии "похожести" для Вашей задачи? Похожими будут считаться только строки с 1 заменой или сдвигом, или более? напрмер, будут ли похожими ABCDABCD и CDABCDAB?

Comment: похожесть = процентное identity 70 % (допуская сдвиги, замены, делеции и тп.)
ваши строки будут похожими, но всё зависит от масштаба. если после сдвига на 2 буквы совпадет несколько сотен - то, конечно, похожи.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, на самом деле, очень хороший! И пока, решение [[@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley)`я самое лучшее. У меня нет лучшей идеи по этому поводу, разве что только XOR`ить строки с определенной "солью" и опять же снова вычислять номер каждого символа. Это будет надежнее, но гораздо дольше, чем "неХОРеные" строки.

---

А вообще советую вам смотреть в сторону PHP-функции **[similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)** . Эта функция вычисляет степень похожести двух строк. Посмотрите её сорцы( они, как мне известно на C++ ), да поймете, как она работает, напишете свою.

Answer (score 1):

такие задачи по силам [нейронным сетям](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Искусственная_нейронная_сеть). хотя очень многое зависит от природы данных. вот например алгоритм [саундекс](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Саундекс) разработанный для имен. даже если он вам не подойдет, должен хотя бы натолкнуть на мысль в какую сторону двигатся

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, здесь поможет преобразование Барроуза-Уилера.